# Beginner C Pointer Problem

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am a new C user have problems with pointers.

The function **add_word(*word_to_add)** should take a c string and add it to the appropriate word_node linked list. However, subsequent additions seem to be overwriting the word element of all nodes in the hash table. I think this is happening because I am setting each nodes word element to be a pointer to word_to_add rather than copying the value of word_to_add.

```
#define HASH_TABLE_SIZE 10
static char **word_list;

struct word_node {
    char* word;
    struct word_node *next;
};

static struct word_node *word_hash_table[HASH_TABLE_SIZE];

static int hash(char *word) {
    int ascii_char;
    int key;

    key = 0;
    while (*word != '\0') {
        ascii_char = tolower(*word);
        key += ascii_char;
        word++;
    }
    key %= HASH_TABLE_SIZE;
    return key;
}


void ws_add_word(char *word_to_add)
{
    int word_position;


    word_position = hash(word_to_add);

    if (word_hash_table[word_position] == NULL)
    {
        struct word_node* p;
        p = malloc(sizeof(struct word_node));;
        p->word = word_to_add;
        p->next = NULL;
        word_hash_table[word_position] = p;
        ++num_words;
    } else {
        struct word_node* p;
        p = word_hash_table[word_position];

        while (p->next != NULL)
        {   
            p = p->next;
        }

        struct word_node* q;
        q = malloc(sizeof(struct word_node));
        q->word = word_to_add;
        q->next = NULL;
        p->next = q;
        ++num_words;
    }
```

Comment: which college just gave out binary trees as homework? seem to be a few similiar questions all at once...

Comment: did you remember to initalize your word_hash_table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just equate two strings or character pointers like:

```
char* p1, p2;
p1=p2; // THIS IS INVALID
```

In your code you have done this mistake two times:--

```
p->word = word_to_add;
```

and

```
q->word = word_to_add;
```

This says that you are making p->word point to word_to_add  which is a pointer.It will just start referring to the same object but not copy the string which you expect.
It won't copy the contents of word_to_add to q->word, which you are assuming to be done.

You need to copy the strings using any string copy function like: strcpy, strncpy or memcpy.

replace  p->word = word_to_add with

```
strcpy(p->word,word_to_add);
```

and similarly

replace  q->word = word_to_add with

```
strcpy(q->word,word_to_add);
```

--

Kr. Alok

Comment: -1: `q->word = word_to_add` is not a mistake.  `word` is a pointer not an array of char.  As long as the caller does `free` the word_to_add then everything is oka.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is ok as is.  If you are having problems, it may be in how you are calling the function.  For example, here is a quick & dirty sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int num_words;

/* paste sample code here */
#define HASH_TABLE_SIZE 10
// rest of code
void ws_add_word(char *word_to_add)
{
    // function code
}
/* end of sample code */

int main (void)
{
    char a[] = "Hello";
    char b[] = "Helkp"; // chosen to have the same hash result

    ws_add_word((char *)&a);
    ws_add_word((char *)&b);
```

}

I compiled with `gcc -g` and ran through `gdb`. Doing so and stepping through `ws_add_word` and examining the contents of `word_hash_table` seems to do what you want.  If it still doesn't work, you should give an example of how you are calling `ws_add_word`.

Also, if you simply change `p->word = word_to_add` with `strcpy(p->word,word_to_add)`, you will probably get a seg fault because `p->word` has not been set to anything meaningful yet.  You need to `p->word = (char *)malloc(N)` where `N` is big enough, and then `strcpy`, if that's what you really want to do.  Whether you want to or not depends on whether the memory location pointed to by `char *word_to_add` will be valid the next time you need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me, except for line 10 in ws_add_word.

Change

```
q->word = word_to_add;
```

to

```
p->word = word_to_add;
```

Comment: Uh, can you clarify why you are suggesting this?

Answer (score 0):

The node's  char pointer 'word' seems to point to the original string rather than holding a copy of its own. This is fine as long as the original string doesn't change. For example:

```
//Assume word_to_add is "String 1"

p->word = word_to_add;

//Now change word_to_add to "String 2"
//After this p->word would be "String 2"
```

I don't know if that was the intended behavior. You might want to allocate memory for every 'word' pointer in the node structure and copy the word_to_add string.